# JSF on Tomcat7 with Java6 system time show Venezuelan Time

Tags: java, jsf, timezone, tomcat7

Edit:JSF Implementation: Mojorra 2.1.9

My web application behaves strangely. When i deploy my app on the server machine, it shows me the time in Venezuela Standart Time. Like this Sun Aug 05 11:46:26 VET 2012

The thing is i am not in Venezuela. I checked timezone configuration on server machine, it is correct. When i run the app on my local machine there is no problem at all, the time is correct. But when deployed the time is wrong.

I put the context param below into web.xml, but it wont help. What is the problem i have no idea

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started tomcat with  "-Duser.timezone=Europe/Istanbul" parameter and the time is now right. Don't understand why default time is Venezuelan Time, but this solved the problem for me. Will look further into this to understand what causes this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The JSF date time converters use by default UTC. Only when you set that context parameter, it will default to the system timezone (the timezone of the underlying server platform). Apparently the server in question is configured with Venezuelan time zone as default (perhaps because it's hosted in Venezuela and maintained by a serveradmin who has no idea what he is doing?).

Removing that context parameter should fix your concrete problem, assuming that you have **not** overridden the JSF default date time converters or their settings, by e.g. a custom converter or by setting the `timeZone` attribute of `<f:convertDateTime>`.

If that does not fix your problem somehow, then try upgrading the JSF implementation (I however don't recall any bugs related to this in Mojarra, so I don't think that upgrading would fix it if you're using Mojarra; I'm not sure about MyFaces though), or try explicitly setting the `timeZone` attribute of every `<f:convertDateTime>` tag throughout the pages.

Comment: Well actually the  server is a virtual machine which is hosted by a server based here and i have administrations right on it. Checked timezone and locale confgiuration and it seems correct. 
I added context parameter after this problem, and it did not make any difference. I cant think anything else that would cause this problem. I did not overwrite JSF converters locale either.

Maybe it is about java settings being misconfigured ? I will check

@BalusC

Comment: Please check the 3rd paragraph which I just added to the answer. Explicitly mentioning the JSF impl/version used would be always helpful, also in all future JSF related questions.

Comment: Thx for the answer, editted my question with JSF imp/version detail. But it is not only on the pages, even log4j's logs are in venezuelan times. Could it be because Java's timezone settings are misconfigured ? 

I checked whether Tomcat's startup arguments has something to do with timezone, but seems like not

@BalusC

Comment: Another possibility would be that "GMT" timezone has in the particular machine been replaced by "VET" for some political reasons... JSF uses `TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")` as default time zone. I'd try fiddling around with a Java application with a `main()` to test/verify the one and other.

Comment: Printed out current time with a simple java application as u suggested. And it was Venezuelan Time. 

The solution was to start Tomcat with -Duser.timezone parameter. Thank you

@BalusC

Comment: Did you just confirm that `TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")` printed Venezuelan time?

Comment: No, ı executed Calendar.getInstance().getTime() it showed Venezuelan Time.

Just tried TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"). The output is:

sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,tran
sitions=0,lastRule=null]